# c# how to find an id from an element in database

Tags: c#, database, primary-key

How i get the `id` from the value `english`, searching all time without any answer.
Thanks for helping

```
test.CourseId = await _context.Course.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Schulfach == english);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code retrieves the whole object. You need to access a single property of this object:

```
var course = await _context.Course.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Schulfach == english);
if (course != null)
{
    test.CourseId = course.CourseId;
}
```